# Retrieving system date in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

How do I get the system date and time in this format:

```
$systime="12/january/2010 10.30 AM "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$systime = date('d/F/o g i A');
```

Sample output:

```
05/March/2010 7 27 AM
```

Comment: thnk u very much....
I got the out put as 05/March/2010 6 36 AM 
but my system time is 12.07 PM. Indian stadard time...

date is correct but time part is not.....
can u pls help...

Comment: Just to be clear...you are in India and where is your server ? :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I am sorry ,, I dont undestand which server you are asking about..

Am developing a web site, so now it runs on my laptop only...

Comment: Let us know your timezone using echo date('T');

Comment: UTC
this is what I get when executing  echo date('T')

Comment: Now thats GMT, which is 5 and 1/2 hours behind IST which is why you are getting a time 5 and half hours behind. I'm not sure how to correct that...may be you can try setting the timezone explicitly like: date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');

Answer (score 6):

To get exactly what you've asked for, you'll need to use [`strtolower()`](http://www.php.net/strtolower) and [`date`](http://www.php.net/date):

```
$systime = strtolower(date("d/F/Y G.i")) . " " . date("A") . " ";
```

You need `strtolower` because there's no built-in way to get lowercase month values, so you need to get that part as `January` and then transform it to lowercase. You can't lowercase the whole thing because you seem to want `AM` or `PM` rather than `am` or `pm`.

Comment: Mr Dominic , Thank you very much....
when I run it I get the out put as 05/march/2010 06/29/46AM

pls see the time part.. now it is 12.02 PM at india...

which is not displayed... can u pls help me..

Comment: time is not getting... Thnak you for your help.

Comment: @Flins - sorry, what do you mean by "time is not getting"?

Comment: Time is not getting displayed correctly. It does not print my system time. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Using date and strftime() we can get the system date.

Example:

```
echo date("d/F/Y g:i A");//It prints 05/March/2010 12:18 PM

echo strftime("%d/%B/%Y %I:%M %p"); //It prints  05/March/2010 12:20 PM
```

Comment: thnk u rekha... how do we get the current time displayed in 12hrs format(AM and PM)

Answer (score -1):

[date()](http://php.net/date) and [time()](http://php.net/time)

Comment: Really, just date().  time() isn't necessary.

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers.