# Get system time using PHP and dealing with offsets/timezones

Tags: php

How can I get the system time, like 10.23 PM, and how do I properly deal with time offsets and timezones?

Comment: Since this is essentially the exact same question is you asked 25 mins ago, you might want to make it more specific. Else, duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384937/retrieving-system-date-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
echo date('g.i A');
```

Check the [PHP `date()` reference](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). `date()` takes an optional second argument which you can use to set a custom timestamp. Without this argument, `date()` returns the current time.

Comment: Thnak you very much
 am from india... so it displays 5.30 hrs back... any solution for this ????

Comment: @Flins, use `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta')` in the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 1):

Find your ***php.ini*** file location and edit it like this:-

1. Find **date.timezone** and set it to your *local timezone name* as used in php.
2. Find **date.default_latitude** and set it to your *server location's latitude*.
3. Find **date.default_longitude** and set it to your *server location's longitude*.

For longitude / latitude, google it with your city name.

**IMPORTANT NOTE** : After you edit this information, save the *php.ini* file and close it. Then RESTART your server. Without restarting, you might not be able to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$time_now=mktime(date('h'),date('i'),date('s'));
print date('h.i A',$time_now);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

`echo date("g:i A")`